# Cross domain iframe click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible in any method to bind a function to events on cross domain iframe ?

I have tried the following with no success

```
jQuery("#itranpayform").load(function () {
        jQuery(this).contents().find("body").on('click','#sumli', function( event ) {
            alert(123);
        });
});
```

Comment: The answer is: No. See [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). If you have control of both domains, there are work arounds.

Comment: This might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage. I've had success with it using popups but haven't tried with an iframe.