# clicking an selected element in python selenium doesnt work using the WebDriverWait/EC/by way

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is the doc I am following http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

This throws exception:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
iframe_xpath = "//*[@id='targetForCaptcha1']/div/div/iframe"
captcha_iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath(iframe_xpath)

driver.switch_to_frame(captcha_iframe)
checkBox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, iframe_xpath)))
checkBox.click()
```

> ```
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
> ```

However this works:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
iframe_xpath = "//*[@id='targetForCaptcha1']/div/div/iframe"
captcha_iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath(iframe_xpath)

action=ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(captcha_iframe)
action.click().perform()
```

The above two are independent sessions running the python script from scratch.

Why doesn't the former work which seems to be the more standard way of doing it?

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: why doesnt the former work ?

Comment: @Andersson I have updated the question, hope now you can withdraw your close request.

Comment: OK. Can you now clarify why you want to click iframe, but not a specific element inside iframe?

Comment: I want to click specific element inside.But the later way which somewhat works for me I found thats the best I can do for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670336/cross-domain-iframe-click-event issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframe is a node of main DOM. After you call `driver.switch_to_frame(captcha_iframe)` you switched to iframes' DOM and node located by `By.XPATH, iframe_xpath` is no more accessible.

So it should be still accessible from main DOM if to skip `driver.switch_to_frame(captcha_iframe)` line

Comment: this is not the issue. hey sorry can you check I updated it again to solve this confusion.

Comment: No. This is the issue. Note that in second code you don't make a switch to iframe. Just add `driver.switch_to_frame(captcha_iframe)` and your second code will fail also

Comment: isn't `action.move_to_element(captcha_iframe)`
equivalent ?

Comment: Absolutely not! It allows to perform mouse hovering over required element

Comment: got it, great, it works when I click an element inside it. but how come does it when we have https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy.

Comment: I guess switching does the trick, you can not access two domains together but once you switch the driver to point to the other you probabably can.